# Connecting my mysql database and Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am following a tutorial for making a login register for Android by tonakami TV in youtube. I encountered a problem where the android app cannot update or connect to the database via LOCALHOST XAMPP.

The app works well, until I send the registry information to the database. As soon as I try to update my database (after the registration) there is no new data inside...

**ServerRequests.java**

```
public class ServerRequests {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 100 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";

    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
    }

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback callBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = callBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

            try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if(jObject.length() == 0){
                    returnedUser = null;
                } else {
                    String name = jObject.getString("name");
                    String email = jObject.getString("email");

                    returnedUser = new User(name, user.username, email, user.password);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("10.0.2.2:8080","root","","test");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_parm($statement, "siss", $id, $name, $username, $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Database:**

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jywLX.png)

I am using the android studio emulator. If you need any further information or code let me know.
Ty for your help.

Comment: When you are binding parameters, why do you say that `$name` is an integer? Surely it's a string. Also, why do you bind the `$id` parameter having never set a value for that variable or used it in the query?

Comment: ah ty for the information. i changed it! but i still got no data inside my database. is the SERVER_ADRESS and the $con=mysqli_connect("10.0.2.2:8080","root","","test") righ? btw. i added a picture of the database...

Comment: It's probably not. It's not common for a MySQL server to be running on port 8080.

Comment: the problem was that the standard port 80 was already in use. so i had to switch to another port.

Comment: Databases don't normally run on either of those ports. The default for MySQL is 3306.

Comment: Yea thats right, but the default port for "Apache" was 80 and this port was in use so i changed this to 8080...

Comment: Okay, but `mysqli_connect` is the command to connect to an SQL database, not a web server.

Comment: okay thats fine, so my first statement is probably wrong. what i have to enter there or how can i find out my right statement? btw. i added a picture of my database to my topic. thank you so far.

Comment: You probably want your server to be "127.0.0.1", although it's hard to say without knowing how you set up your SQL server.

Comment: i am using the one from xampp :)

Comment: So unless you've changed the port, it should be at "127.0.0.1".

Comment: here you can see, when i am running the app on emulator is should use 10.0.2.2 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html ------ i dont know what i have to write now in the php script and what in the SERVER_ADRESS in the ServerRequests.java...

Comment: Okay. Are you running your SQL server in the Android emulator then?

Comment: i am not sure? i am running the app with the android emulator. and i try to update my database (phpmyadmin) with the app on the emulator.

Comment: Okay. I don't know enough about Android development to know how to run a database server on an Android emulator. I have only ever used SQLite on Android. I hope you can find someone else to answer your questions.

Comment: okay no problem. thank you. some lines of my code a depricated. is this a problem in the usage?

Comment: Ideally you should avoid using deprecated functions, but it's not the end of the world if you do and your code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the type of data your binding to username, am not sure if your using your username as an integer.

See below i have changed it to bind a string using "s".

Refere to PHP Manual on how to bind different data types. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters)

```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("10.0.2.2", "root", "", "test");
    /**
     * Don't use any port as mysql uses port 3306
     * thats why i have removed 8080, this is used to access phpmyadmin but not mysql that why we are including it from the frontend
     * but not when accessing it from terminal or as in our case on php
     */
    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo json_encode("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    /* check if server is alive */
    if ($mysqli->ping()) {
        //now lets pass the post to the function register with the POST params
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            //since we have intialised the class from above
            $query = "INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['password']);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            if ($result) {
                echo json_encode('user created successful');
            } else {
                echo json_encode($mysqli->error);
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode('POST is empty');
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
```

Comment: hey yes, it was my mistake because i didnt noticed to change it while i was watching the tutorial. but it still doesnt stores data in my database...

Comment: Let me edit the whole thing using object oriented style

Comment: okay ty so far. i am not sure if i am doing the connection right. i use the database from xampp and the apache too. the problem was port 80 for apache was in use so i changed it to 8080. so i got trouble with: $con=mysqli_connect("10.0.2.2:8080","root","","test"); and i also got trouble with:  public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";

Comment: You were not doing the connection right. remove the port 8080 from connection string.

Comment: so i will need:     public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/"; ? SO MUCH THANKS! Do i have do edit anything on the php script? I am just curious because in your php script you say $mysqli double!

Comment: Made a mistake, i have remove on initialization. also on the php script i have added a few checks for checking connection and returning any errors. also on the query i have removed id have a look at it

Comment: oh okay ty! But it still does not store any date in my database. i dont think that the php script is wrong. maybe there is a mistake in the code? everytime i enter data in the text fields and when i click the login button i see a message for a few seconds "Processing" and then it direct me to the "login" activity as i want. but the data isnt in the database -.-! I do not get any error message from the php script.

Comment: I would advise you use a tool like Postman so emulate your post request in order to know if your PHP script really works. Postman is available here https://www.getpostman.com/ dowload and then find your way around creating a POST request. or create a log file and log messages to debug the scrip. If the script works you can then concentrate with your app code and debug it

Comment: This gave me the right solution: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-user-registration-tutorial/